# How to get all elements from webpage using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, tags, html

My Python code is only finding the first article of the HTML, so it is printing the same link. How do I get all article tags from the HTML? Thanks.

Python code:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("article")
for i in links:
    if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='inner-article']/a//div[@class='sold_out_tag']").get_attribute("innerHTML") == "sold out":
        print("sold out")
        link = ((driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='inner-article']/a").get_attribute("href")))
        print(link)
    else:
        print("available")
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

HTML:

```
<article>
   <div class="inner-article"><a style="height:81px;" 
   href="/shop/jackets/jly8dgwqu/w10m2pybx"><img width="81" height="81" 
   src="//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/139432/vi/AHP1l8fMIcA.jpg" 
   alt="Ahp1l8fmica"><div class="sold_out_tag">sold out</div></a></div>
</article>
<article>
   <div class="inner-article"><a style="height:81px;" 
   href="/shop/jackets/jly8dgwqu/w10m2pybx"><img width="81" height="81" 
   src="//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/139432/vi/AHP1l8fMIcA.jpg" 
   alt="Ahp1l8fmica"><div class="sold_out_tag">sold out</div></a></div>
</article>
```

Comment: When you say " only finding the first article of the html," What is your output exactly?

Comment: Can you specify in detail what happened when you ran your code?  And what prevents you to get all article tags from the html?

Comment: The problem is inside your if statement you're calling the `find_element` code on the *driver*. You need to call it on `i` and modify your XPath accordingly

Comment: 1. My output is the first link (see the first href) for however many links there are. If there are say 50 links on the page, it prints the first link 50 times.

Comment: 2. See #1. I think I am getting all the elements, I think the execution inside the for loop is wrong.

Comment: Mangohero, I tried replacing driver with i in driver.find_element_by so it became i.find_element_by, but I just got the same result

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you'll need a special maneuver by Selenium called [Action Chains](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains). You can import it at the top like so:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Then proceed as follows:

```
articles = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('article')
for article in articles:
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(article).perform()
    if article.find_element_by_tag_name('a').text == "sold out":
         print("sold out")
         link = article.find_element_by_xpath('div/a').get_attribute('href')
         print(link)
    else:
         print("available")
```

For each article web element, you can call the same methods from the `driver` to look in just that element. XPath's double slash (`//`) dictates that it searches the whole DOM without regards to any specific element (which is why it locates the same element each time), so you'd need to search it's direct children (ie. `/`).

Edit: The element with the sold out text, by default, has a CSS property of `display: none;`. The only way to trigger the sold out text is by doing a mouseover each element. Luckily, Selenium has this capability too. I've also changed my original code a bit, items that aren't sold out don't have a div with a "sold out tag" class, so that would lead to an error.

Comment: This actually just got the same result, I'm not sure why

Comment: hmm. send the link of the page you're extracting, I'll see if it's something on my end

Comment: http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all                                                                         thanks for the help

Comment: No problem! glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` you have shared if you want to print the `href`s of the nodes with text `sold out` you can use the following code block :

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("article")
for i in links:
    if "sold out" in i.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='inner-article']/a//div[@class='sold_out_tag']").get_attribute("innerHTML") :
        print("sold out")
        print(i.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='inner-article']/a").get_attribute("href"))
```